# Binding Xaml UserControl view to it's code behind, but code behind bound to other object

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding, binding

I have a UserControl defined by Xaml and code behind. It should update as the model on which it is based changes.

I have constructed each instance of these controls in code, and set up bindings to some object `_interestingSystem`.

```
var newViewInstance = new BroadcastCell
{
    HeartbeatStatus = Heartbeat.Status.NotRx,
    BindingContext = _interestingSystem,
};
broadcastCell.SetBinding(BroadcastCell.HeartbeatProperty, "HeartbeatStatus");
StatkStack.Children.Add(broadcastCell);
```

These bindings work, and I can see the code-behind responding to the model changes just fine.

Now I want to bind my view to the code-behind after a little modification and adjustment.
**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="56" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Text="{Binding Title, FallbackValue=TestTitle, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1"  />
    <Label Text="{Binding SecondaryLine, FallbackValue=Test2nd}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  />
</Grid>
```

**Code-behind**

```
public Heartbeat.Status CurrentStatus;

static void OnHeartbeatStatusChanged(BindableObject sender, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var thisInstance = (BroadcastCell)sender;
    var newStatus = (Heartbeat.Status)newValue;
    thisInstance.CurrentStatus= newStatus;
}

private void UpdateAndModifyResult()
{
    SecondaryLine = $"{DateTime.Now} {CurrentStatus} @ {AnotherStatus}";
}

public String SecondaryLine
{
    get { return _secondaryLine; }
    set
    {
        _secondaryLine = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Can I set the binding of the Xaml to the code-behind, and the code behind to another object as I am trying?
Or do I need to hard-code in the xaml property name into the code-behind to update them 'manually'?

Answer (score 0):

In XAML, you can set the source of a `Binding` to the root `BroadcastCell` by using the `FindAncestor` binding mode like this:

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:BroadcastCell}}, Path=SecondaryLine}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

When loading the XAML, the binding engine will look up the visual tree for the first `BroadcastCell` object and bind to its `SecondaryLine` property.

Alternatively, you could directly bind your view to your model without the need to manually set any kind of binding in your code-behind by doing this:

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding Heartbeat.Status}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

provided that you set the `DataContext` of your view to the correct source object. Your code-behind would become:

```cs
broadcastCell.DataContext = _interestingSystem;
```

This is more appropriate than defining a binding in the code-behind.